# Best way to create template file in bazel macro

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to write a macro to abstract over a bunch of rules that I need for a couple of different targets. One thing that I need to do is to create a small file that will be treated as a source file in a later rule. If this was a rule I would just use [expand_template](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#expand_template). The best I can currently come up with involves a `native.genrule` and making sure I escape everything correctly and passing it to echo.

I would hope there is an easier way.

Code in question:

```
  racket_contents = """
#lang racket/base
(require
  "bootstrap-compiler.rkt"
  racket/runtime-path)
(define-runtime-path library-compiler-list-file "%s")
(run-bootstrap-compiler library-compiler-list-file #"%s_main")
""" % (source_file_list, short_name)

  native.genrule(
      name = "racketize_" + name,
      outs = [racket_src_name],
      cmd = "echo >>$@ '%s'" % racket_contents,
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a generic rule for expanding templates.

genfile.bzl

```
def _genfile_impl(ctx):
    ctx.actions.expand_template(
        template = ctx.file.template,
        output = ctx.file.output,
        substitutions = substitutions,
    )
    return [
        DefaultInfo(files = depset([ctx.file.output])),
    ]

genfile = rule(
    implementation = _genfile_impl,
    attrs = {
        "template": attr.label(
            mandatory = True,
            allow_single_file = True,
        ),
        "output": attr.output(
            mandatory = True,
        ),
        "substitutions": attr.string_dict(),
    },
)
```

racket.tpl

```
#lang racket/base
(require
  "bootstrap-compiler.rkt"
  racket/runtime-path)
(define-runtime-path library-compiler-list-file "TMPL_SOURCE_FILES")
(run-bootstrap-compiler library-compiler-list-file #"TMPL_SHORTNAME_main")
```

BUILD

```
load("//:genfile.bzl", "genfile")

genfile(
  name = "racket",
  output = "racket.out",
  template = "racket.tpl",
  substitutions = {
    "TMPL_SOURCE_FILES": ",",join(["n1","n2"]),
    "TMPL_SHORTNAME": "shortname",
  },
)
```